# subprocess input commands when running executable

Tags: python, automation, subprocess, command-line-interface, stm32

STM32 cube programmer CLI. In command terminal I can type: `C:\location\bin>STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=COM1 -w C:\location\test.bin 0x08000000`  This programs the device when using the command line.

When I use my python script. It fails.

```
import os
import subprocess

#inputting commands when cli tool is running
connection = "C:\location\\bin>STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe"
subprocess.check_output([connection, '-c', '-c port=COM14' '-w C:\source\test.bin', '0x08000000'])
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
# Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "C:\source\q.py", line 14, in <module>
# subprocess.check_output([connection, '-c', '-c port=COM14' '-w C:\source\test.bin', '0x08000000'])
# File "C:\source\python_version\py3110\Lib\subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
# return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
# #            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# File "C:\source\python_version\py3110\Lib\subprocess.py", line 548, in run
# with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
# #          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# File "C:\source\python_version\py3110\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
# self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
# File "C:\source\python_version\py3110\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1509, in _execute_child
# hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
# #                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Expecting the device to program. When manually running the bin using the CLI tool the device program.
Why is the above code not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are failing to:

- differentiate between your prompt `C:\location\bin>` and your command `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe`, and also
- separate your parameters because `-c port=COM1` is two separate parameters

I don't have (or want) Windows so this is untested, but you will need something more like:

```
cmd = [
   r'C:\location\bin\STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe',
   '-c', 'port=COM1',
   '-w', r'C:\location\test.bin',
   '0x08000000'
]

subprocess.checkoutput(cmd)
```